# Is an Ubuntu One account required in order to use Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one

Is an Ubuntu One account required in order to use Ubuntu 13.10? If an account is not required, why was I asked for Ubuntu One credentials when installing Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No an Ubuntu One account is not required, and that step can be skipped.

The Ubuntu 13.10 installation wizard asks for the Ubuntu One username and password, in order to get the service automatically installed, so in case you do have an account.

Comment: Okay. It does seem a little pushy to have no "I don't want this, please skip" type option, but Ubuntu One is a great service and people should take advantage of it.